# how to update image in asp.net core razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

New to asp.net core razor pages (asp.net core 3.1)
How do I change an image corresponding to an info that comes from a remote service? the image is defined at the header part of the app _Layout page.
Do I need to define a shared page to contain that image and @Renderpage within the header part of the _layout page? (Tried to do that but @Renderpage is not recognize d within the header part....)
10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I change an image corresponding to an info that comes from a remote service? the image is defined at the header part of the app _Layout page.

If you call that remote service within your razor page handler, to pass it to the page, you can try to use ViewData, like below.

In page handler

```
//code logic here
//...
//call remote service and get URL to image

ViewData["myimg"] = "https://xxxx/imgs/xxxx.png";
```

In _Layout page

```
<img id="myimg" src="@ViewData["myimg"]" width="25" height="25" />
```

Besides, if you call that remote service on client side via Ajax etc, you can dynamically change value of `src` attribute, like below.

```
$("#myimg").attr("src", "your_img_url_here");
```